# T-SQL data transformation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a result set like this:

```
ID  Value
1    100
2    50
3    200
4    30
-    -
-    -
```

I want it to transform into following:

```
Value1 Value2
100      50
200      30
-        -
-        -
```

How to do it with T-SQL?

Comment: Are ids guaranteed to be consecutive (no gaps between them)?

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you are trying to achieve and also which version of SQL you are using.

Comment: IDs are consecutive starting from 1 and no gap. I use SOL Server 2005

Comment: If your sequence is without gaps, @t-clausen.dk solution is more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
select a.Value, b.Value
from
(
    select row_number() over(order by ID) [rn], Value
    from @t
)a
left join
(
    select row_number() over(order by ID) [rn], Value
    from @t
)b on b.rn = a.rn + 1
where a.rn % 2 = 1
```

Sample data:

```
declare @t table (ID int, Value int)

insert @t values (1,100), (2,50), (3,200), (4,30)
```

Output:

```
Value       Value
----------- -----------
100         50
200         30
```

Comment: Left join instead of join perhaps ? Try with 5 rows like in my example.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, Sure, but it may depend on task... I updated my answer :-)

Comment: It was only fair you got the credit, since there was to information about the ID being without gabs and I just assumed there wasn't. You code takes that into account. But without gabs he should use my solution, because of performance (as you mentioned).

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, Yep I wrote OP that.

Comment: t-clausen.dk solution also good as long as there is no gap. But the other solution I selected at least protects from such type of bug just in case there is a gap in IDs.

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @t table (id int, v int)

insert @t values (1, 10)
insert @t values (2, 20)
insert @t values (3, 30)
insert @t values (4, 40)
insert @t values (5, 50)


select t1.v, t2.v
from @t t1 
left join @t t2 
on t1.id + 1 = t2.id
where t1.id %2 = 1
```